# What's the reason of the linked list has a zero beginning of the beginning? C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, output, nodes

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void add(struct Node *head, int n) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    Node *cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        if(cur->next == NULL) {
            cur->next = newNode;
            return;
        }

        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void display(struct Node *head) {
    Node *list = head;
    while(list) {
        cout << list->data << " ";
        list = list->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *newHead;
    struct Node *head = new Node;
    int ar[]={2,5,46,7,55};
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        add(head,ar[i]);
    }
    display(head);
}
```

OUTPUT:

> 0 2 5 46 7 55

What's the reason of the linked list has a zero of the beginning? 
And how can I fix it? I do not want to print zero.

If you see some mistakes in my code, please tell me. I am new at coding.

Comment: `head` also has an unitialized value.

Comment: You don't need to specify `struct` before naming a `struct` as a type in c++. A `struct` is implicitly a type name.

Comment: `struct Node *head = new Node;` you're adding a node with an uninitialized value (which your compiler is nice enough to make 0) to the beginning of your list.

Comment: Your teacher seems to be stuck in the 90s. You should supplement that course with a good C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, you allocate an uninitialized instance of `Node` and store the pointer in `head`. You never assign the `head->data` of that node, so that value is indeterminate. Same holds for `head->next`. When those values are read in `add` and `display`, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

> And how can I fix it?

Firstly, initialize `head` in `main` to avoid undefined behaviour:

```
Node *head = new Node();
//                   ^^ these are important
```

Then you could do one of these things:

a) Skip the first node using `display(head->next);` instead of `display(head);`

b) Initialize the `head` to the first value that you want

```
head->data = ar[0];
for(int i=1; i<5;i++)
// ...
```

c) Redesign your API to not require the user to allocate the first node separately. More details about this in Remy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. When you allocate the `head` node, you are not assigning any value to its `data` member, so it holds a random value that *happens* to be 0 in your case. And you are not initializing its `next` member either, which means `add()` and `display()` will not work correctly.
2. in `add()`, if `head` is NULL, no node is added to the list (you don't update the caller's `Node*` variable to point at the new node), and you leak the allocated `newNode`.
3. you are leaking all of the allocated nodes when exiting from `main()`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>    

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int value) : data(value), next(0) {}
};

void add(Node* &head, int n) {
    Node **newNode = &head;
    while (*newNode) {
        newNode = &((*newNode)->next);
    }
    *newNode = new Node(n);
}

void display(Node *head) {
    Node *cur = head;
    while (cur) {
        std::cout << cur->data << " ";
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void clear(Node* &head) {
    Node *cur = head;
    head = NULL;
    while (cur) {
        Node *next = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    int ar[] = {2, 5, 46, 7, 55};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        add(head, ar[i]);
    }
    display(head);
    clear(head);
    return 0;
}
```

And then, when you get that working, throw it all away and use the STL's [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void display(const std::list<int> &mylist) {
    for(std::list<int>::const_iterator iter = mylist.begin(); iter != mylist.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    int ar[] = {2, 5, 46, 7, 55};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        mylist.push_back(ar[i]);
    }

    /* or:
    int ar[] = {2, 5, 46, 7, 55};
    std::list<int> mylist(ar, ar+5);
    */

    display(mylist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh, another level of indirection for head? Wouldn't it be easier to make it pass by reference?

Comment: @scohe001: a reference is still an indirection when used as a function parameter. And most compilers implement references using pointers anyway.  But whatever, I updated my example.